# Retornando Fragmento de HTML com Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Existe a possibilidade de retornar somente um fragmento do código de uma página com o `AJAX` `JQuery`?

O que quero fazer é:

Tenho uma página onde através do `POST` envio o ID com o `AJAX`, e gero o corpo de um modal `<div class="modal-body">`, porém gostaria de ter outra div para retornar o cabeçalho deste modal `<div class="modal-header">`.

Existe alguma forma de chamar através do resultado do `AJAX` cada `div` individualmente para que haja a alteração do `HTML` via `Javascript`?

---

### Adicionais

O que tenho até o momento seria isso:

```
<script>
    function teste(){
        var url = "&id="+teste;
        $.ajax({
        url: "conv_modal_results.php",
        dataType:"HTML",
        type: "POST",           
        data: url,
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('.modal-body').html('<div align="center"><img src="img/loading.gif" /></div>');
        },
        sucess: function(data){
            setTimeout($('.modal-body').html(data),2000);   
        }   
        });
    }
</script>

<input type="button" value="botaozinho" onClick="teste()">
<div class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Carregando....</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

No conv_modal_results.php eu tenho o seguinte retorno

```
<div id="corpo_modal" class="row">
Aqui vai o corpo do modal...
</div>
```

O que eu quero é poder adicionar mais um `div` e poder chamar cada uma individualmente no resultado, utilizando algo como o `.find()` do `JQuery` para utilizar somente aquele pedaço do HTML

Comment: Sim é possível. Se explicares um pouco mais o que o AJAX deve retornar e mostrares mais da estrutur código podemos também responder com um exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz uma simulação de algo próximo do que você precisa assim:

No PHP, retorno um JSON de um array contendo o HTML do header e do Body:

```
<?php
    $header = "<div>Meu Header</div>";
    $body = "<div>Conteúdo</div>";

    echo json_encode(array($header, $body)); 
?>
```

Com o javascript, faço a chamada ajax do script e no sucesso o parse do JSON para obter o array. Depois é só inserir o conteúdo no lugar e exibir a modal:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'index.php',               
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
        if(result){
            var resultObj = JSON.parse(result);
            $("#minhaModal .modal-header").html(resultObj[0]);
            $("#minhaModal .modal-body").html(resultObj[1]);
            $("#minhaModal").modal("show");                     
        } 
        else {
            alert("Erro");
        }
    }
});
```